# How to check if the currently logged on user is using roaming profile?

Tags: c#, .net, environment

How can I check if the current user is using roaming profile?

Is there any .net framework library that can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this is to call the Win32 shell function [GetProfileType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762279(VS.85).aspx).  You would need to use P/Invoke to make the call and then check the out value of the pdwFlags parameter for PT_ROAMING (which has the value of 2).

I don't see a sample signature for this function on pinvoke.net but with such a simple signature:

```
BOOL WINAPI GetProfileType(      
    DWORD *pdwFlags
);
```

Creating one would not be hard.

Comment: @Bubbafat: Is it true that user with roaming profile doesn't have installation rights by default? How to set those permissions then?

Answer (score 2):

```
    [DllImport("Userenv.dll", EntryPoint = "GetProfileType", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool GetProfileType(ref uint pdwflags);

    [Flags]
    enum Win32ProfileType : uint { 
        Local=0x00,
        Temporary=0x01,
        Roaming=0x02,
        Mandatory=0x04
    }


    public void SomeTest()
    {
        uint type = 0;
        if (GetProfileType(ref type)) {
            //todo
        }
    }
```