# Check Which user profile is mounted on device

Tags: c#, user-profile

I want to check which user profile is assigned to my machine whether it is Roaming or Local how can I check it using c# and is there any entry of it in registry.

Thank you in Advanced

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/69876a86-f5f0-4ffd-a1d5-5a5683c8f805/how-to-detect-if-a-user-profile-is-roaming?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if the currently logged on user is using roaming profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200173/how-to-check-if-the-currently-logged-on-user-is-using-roaming-profile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one way would be to call the win32 api function [`GetProfileType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-getprofiletype).

In order to use it you will have to declare it as a method and use the [`DllImport` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=net-6.0)  like this:

```
[DllImport("Userenv.dll", EntryPoint = "GetProfileType", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool GetProfileType(out ProfileType dwflags);
```

As I have not seen a desciption of the flag values, you will have to test it yourself. As soon as you figured out which value is returned for which profile type, you might want to create an enumeration like the following one:

```
[Flags]
public enum ProfileType : uint
{
    Local = 0x00,
    Temporary = 0x01,
    Roaming = 0x02,
    Mandatory = 0x04
}
```

Usage:

```
ProfileType profileType;

if (!GetProfileType(ref profileType))
{
  // Error handling here...
}

if (profileType.HasFlag(ProfileType.Local))
{
  // We have a local profile...
}
```

For details about the different [User profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776892(v=vs.85)) check the following links:

- [Local User Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776894(v=vs.85))
- [Mandatory User Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776895(v=vs.85))
- [Roaming User Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776897(v=vs.85))
- [Temporary User Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776898(v=vs.85))

Update: Oh... it seems someone has already done the work. I've updated my answer with the (presumably) correct values and marked the question as duplicate.

Comment: what to give value of dwflagsin GetProfileType method as I am  completely unaware of this method

Comment: @PratikshaNatekar What do you mean with "for my machine"? The profile type is bound to the user profiles.